# join one row from one mysql table to multiple row in second table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have question about mysql queries. The story goes something like this: I have table in which I store information about college trips. This table has attributes about name of a trip, id of a trip and activity. Activity can be 0 or 1, depending if trip is still active (1) or inactive (0). In second table I have information about students that have applied for trips with attributes: id, name, surname and id of a trip that student have applied for. I don't know mysql query that will show me only students that have applied for trips that are still active (acitivity=1).

For example let's have a look at these tables:

```
TRIPS

id | trip     | activity
---+----------+-----------
1  | Paris    | 0
2  | London   | 1
3  | Belgrade | 0
4  | Prague   | 1

STUDENTS

id | name     | id_trip
---+----------+-----------
1  | Mark     | 3
2  | Ana      | 1
3  | Tom      | 2
4  | Maya     | 3
5  | Rachel   | 4
6  | John     | 2



   RESULT

    id | name     | id_trip | trip    | activity
    ---+----------+---------+---------+---------
    3  | Tom      | 2       | London  | 1
    5  | Rachel   | 4       | Prague  | 1
    6  | John     | 2       | London  | 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
s.id, 
s.name, 
s.id_trip, 
t.trip, 
t.activity
FROM 
STUDENTS AS s
INNER JOIN TRIPS AS t ON ( t.id = s.id_trip ) 
WHERE
t.id = 1
```

hope this will work.

Comment: I have only to change t.id=1 to t.activity=1. Thank you! Great job! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.id_trip, t.name, t.activity
FROM students s
JOIN trips t
ON s.id_trip = t.id
WHERE t.activity = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from students s
join trips t
on  s.id_trip = t.id
where t. activity =1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may solve your problem:

```
select s.id as id, s.name as name,t.trip as trip, 
t.activity as activity from trips t 
join  students s on 
t.id = s.id_trip 
where t.activity = 1
```